# Can I give a WordPress website 644 file permissions?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, permissions

I have a WordPress website. If I give all files 644 permissions to have better security and prevent malware getting inside my website, will that break anything?

Comment: Try it out and find out?

Comment: it will not break anything for as long as the server (apache or nginx or whatever you're using) is the owner of these files.

Comment: i just tried it and its brocken my website.
what i wnat is :

prevent anybody to edit or add or delete files but still can read it 

554 or i dont know which permission i need to use

Comment: [Changing File Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) and [Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) are a recommended read :)

Comment: i read it already but this recommended will not prevent website form malware